# Load a cell below data upon the users choice in the first cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Have a specific question.

I'm building a choice-based TableView app.

Let's say if the user clicks on the second button in the first cell - he is shown the second cell data (if he clicks A it would be data 1, if B - data 2). The first cell then becomes inactive.

In the second cell again he has two options - and then the third cell ... and so on.

Browsed internet all over for this and have no clue.

Thank you!

Appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your question quite well, should the flow be like this :

1 ) The user sees only one cell containing, let's say, two pictures corresponding to two different choices

2 ) The user selects one of the pictures

3) A second cell appears below the first one ( same type of cell, with two pictures ). User interaction with the first cell is then disabled.

If that's it, a solution would be to implement a custom table view cell with two custom buttons ( UIButton ) corresponding to your choices.
These custom buttons could have an NSString property called "choice" accessible from your table view controller.

You can then add a counter on your table view controller to know how many cells should be displayed. It starts at 1 with the first cell.
When the user would touch one of the buttons, this counter would be incremented by one.
You can manage your data with the choice the user picked up and then reload your tableview.

I didn't write code, because it would represent dozens of lines and you're just asking for ideas.

Hope it helps !

Comment: That is a fantastic idea. I will definitely try it out. Thank you.

Comment: I'm thinking about adding stylized buttons instead of images and thus keep away from the gesture recognizer

Comment: For sure, that's even better, I don't really know why I told you to use UIViews actually..